# updating beanstalk elastic load balancer via ebextension

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

been trying to to apply an update of health check path from **"/"** to **"/pogi"** via elastic beanstalk ebextension however no changes happening using these approach:

```
Resources:
  AWSEBLoadBalancer:
    Type: "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer"
    Properties:
      HealthCheck:
        HealthyThreshold: 3
        Interval: 30
        Target: HTTPS:443/pogi
        Timeout: 5
        UnhealthyThreshold: 5
```

I even tried this one too:

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elb:loadbalancer
    option_name: LoadBalancerHTTPSPort
    value: "443"
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application
    option_name: Application Healthcheck URL
    value: "/pogi"
```

may I ask for your help and advise on anything I missed here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> may I ask for your help and advise on anything I missed here?

This could be due to  [precedence of config options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html#configuration-options-precedence).  `.ebextentions` have **low** precedence, so if you set these settings using any other method (manually, aws cli, or used saved configurations), the `.ebextentions` will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can find, there are two options: [aws:elb:healthcheck](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-elbhealthcheck) or [AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer HealthCheck](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-elb-health-check.html).

I think the problem with your current code is that according to the docs, the values need to be strings and my need to be quoted.

```
Resources:
  AWSEBLoadBalancer:
    Type: "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer"
    Properties:
      HealthCheck:
        HealthyThreshold: "3"
        Interval: "30"
        Timeout: "5"
        UnhealthyThreshold: "5"
option_settings:
  aws:elb:healthcheck:
    HealthyThreshold: "3"
    Interval: "30"
    Timeout: "5"
    UnhealthyThreshold: "5"
```